# How to load properties from an external file in SOAP UI?

Tags: properties, soapui

Currently, when I tried with an external *csv/excel*, some junk values are getting updated as properties. Please provide an external file snapshot on how to provide property values to import it in SOAP UI.

Comment: Strangely and frustratingly, SoapUI documentation does not specify what file format the properties file should be in e.g. csv, json etc. Apparently you need to search posts in SO to find that the correct format is PropertyName=PropertyValue

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Custom Properties import/export feature? It uses an xml document.

You can find it by clicking on your Project/TestSuite/TestCase/TestStep, then looking in the *bottom-left corner*. Click on the "Custom Properties" tab. There should be property import and export buttons.

There may also be something here which could help you:

http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/working-with-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

first you should save your external file like this  *.properties   (like test.properties file type .properties).  inside file there should be key=value  Record[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4xuK.png)